# How do i create a single route using Express.js to create a RESTful api with amazon Api Getaway and lambda

Tags: javascript, node.js, rest, amazon-web-services, lambda

I'd been trying to build a Node.js / Express.js api using the amazon Getaway and Lambda services.

So far i was able to expose on GET web service using this frameworks, platform combinations, what i need to know is, shall i create a new file / code zip bundle for each service that i wan to expose using Amazon API Getaway?

The reason for this question is, i create a single Express.js route that holds all the paths and it's methods:

```
route.get('/', function(res, req){
    ....
})

route.get('/:id', function(res, req){
    ....
})

route.get('/user/', function(res, req){
    ....
})
```

Using Amazon Api Getaway i create one resource and one method for each lambda function but when i try to send paths to it i get the same result as if the Express.js app only had 1 route available.

Thanks!